# Android O Beta Preview 3 - Lists and Adapters issues?

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter, baseadapter, android-8.0-oreo

I'm running the latest developer preview of Android O and I'm seeing the following behaviours:

- I have various lists inside dialog fragments that use custom adapters which extend BaseAdapter. These are no longer selectable on Android O.
- I have other lists inside fragments (not dialog fragments) which
  use custom adapters that extend ArrayAdapter<>. These work fine on Android O.
- When I try and change my dialog fragment list adapters to extend ArrayAdapter<>, the lists still are not    selectable.

Below is a sample I wrote to recreate the problem I'm experiencing inside my app. I have an activity that creates a dialog fragment which has a list inside. The list adapter extends BaseAdapter. The list is unresponsive and the OnItemClickListener is never fired.

This pattern worked perfectly in my app until Android O.

Has anyone else experienced this problem? I've had a hunt around the documentation and it doesn't mention any changes around adapters/lists.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Activity:

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    List<String> waFilms = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
      setUpList();

      Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.launchButton);
      button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View view) {
          ListDialogFragment ldf =ListDialogFragment.getInstance(waFilms);
          ldf.show(getFragmentManager(), "ListDialogFragment.");
      }
    });
   }
    private void setUpList() {
      waFilms.add(0, "Bottlerocket");
      waFilms.add(1, "Rushmore");
      waFilms.add(2, "The Royal Tenenbaums");
      waFilms.add(3, "The Life Aquatic");
      waFilms.add(4, "The Darjeeling Limited");
      waFilms.add(5, "Fantastic Mr Fox");
      waFilms.add(6, "Moonrise Kingdom");
      waFilms.add(7, "The Grand Budapest Hotel");
     }
   }
```

Dialog Fragment:

```
public class ListDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

  List<String> waFilms = new ArrayList<>();

  public static ListDialogFragment getInstance(List<String> answerOptions) {
    ListDialogFragment f = new ListDialogFragment();
    f.waFilms = answerOptions;
    return f;
  }

  @NonNull
  @Override
  public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ListView list = (ListView) View.inflate(getActivity(), R.layout.dialog_fragment_list, null);
    list.setAdapter(new SimpleAdapter(2, waFilms, getActivity()));
    list.setOnItemClickListener(onClickListener);

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    builder.setTitle("Please pick a film.");
    builder.setView(list);
    Dialog d = builder.create();
    d.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
    return d;
  }

  AdapterView.OnItemClickListener onClickListener = new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
      String chosenOption = waFilms.get(position);
      Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Your chosen film is: " + chosenOption, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
  };
}
```

Adapter:

```
public class SimpleAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

  private List<String> items;
  private Context context;
  private int selection;

  public SimpleAdapter(int selection, List<String> items, Context context) {
    super();
    this.items = items;
    this.selection = selection;
    this.context = context;
  }

  @Override
  public int getCount() {
    return items.size();
  }

  @Override
  public Object getItem(int i) {
    return items.get(i);
  }

  @Override
  public long getItemId(int i) {
    return i;
  }

  @Override
  public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (convertView == null)
      convertView = ((LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(R.layout.form_dialog_list_item, null);

    TextView text = convertView.findViewById(R.id.listTextView);
    ImageView star = convertView.findViewById(R.id.listSelectionIcon);

    star.setVisibility(position == selection ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
    text.setText(items.get(position));

    return convertView;
  }

  public List<String> getItems() {
    return items;
  }
}
```

[image: Main Activity]

[image: DialogFragment with list]